# Adding images inside a Tooltip in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am trying to insert images and other html content inside a Tooltip in Flex 4 by making the text htmlText similar to this:

http://blogagic.com/190/easy-flex-tooltip-customization-using-html-tags

My HTMLToolTip class:

```
package custom
{
    import mx.controls.ToolTip;

  public class HTMLToolTip extends ToolTip
  {
    public function HTMLToolTip()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function commitProperties():void{
        super.commitProperties();
        textField.htmlText = text;
    }
  }
}
```

and on Tooltip Creation, I set the class as the ToolTipManager class

```
protected function helpToolTip_toolTipCreateHandler(event:ToolTipEvent):void
{   
        ToolTipManager.toolTipClass = HTMLToolTip;
        helpToolTip.tooltip = "<img src='ui_graphic/testimage.png' width='20' height='20'/> this is a <b>tool</b> tip";
}
```

But it just doesn't seem to work anymore in Flex 4 (judging from various comments online too). The images just don't show up. Every other basic HTML-tag I have tried work fine. Has anyone gotten this to work on Flex 4, or should I look into another (more complex) solution?

Comment: In Flex 4 I would use PopUpAnchor or SkinnablePopUpContainer to create heavily customized tooltips like these.

Answer (score 0):

Create tooltip class extends RichText:

```
package classes
{
    import mx.core.IToolTip;

    import spark.components.RichText;
    import spark.utils.TextFlowUtil;

    public class RichToolTip extends RichText implements IToolTip
    {
        public function RichToolTip()
        {
            super();

            mouseEnabled = false;
            mouseChildren = false;
            setStyle("backgroundColor", "0xeeeeee");
        }

        override public function set text(value:String):void 
        {
            textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(value);
        } 
    }
}
```

In application set new tooltip class:

```
ToolTipManager.toolTipClass = RichToolTip;
```

And add tooltip for example over button:

```
btn.toolTip = "<div><img source='assets/bender_saved.png' width='20' height='20' /><p>this is a test <span fontWeight='bold'>bold</span></p></div>";
```